# LP Maximising a negative objective function

Tags: linear-programming

How can I turn this into canonical form and then use the two-phase simplex method to solve it?

$$max\quad -2x_1-x_2-x_3 \\
\text{subject to: }-x_1-x_3 \le -1 \\
-x_1+x_2 \le -2 \\
-x_2+x_3 \le -1 \\
x_1,x_2,x_3 \ge 0
$$

When I put it into the tableau with only slack variables there are no negative coefficients in the bottom room to find the column to pivot around